# where should put showSchedule method in school system

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, domain-driven-design, class-design

In my school management system I have this partial  class diagram:

[image]

**1-** In one use case student want to see his schedule of classes in week. this is what i suppose to do:

get `student` object from session and call method `getSchedule()` on that and it will give me schedule(this method calls `StudentCourse`, `Course` for getting schedule).

Is this good place to put `getSchedule()` method or I should place it elsewhere?

..................................................

**2-** In another use class student's parent want to see his child class schedule, I plan to do something like this:

Because I have some use cases that parent want to see some other student information(course mark...), I create interface `StudentParentInterface` that have method `getSchedule()` and other methods and student implement `StudentParentInterface`, then parent has reference to `StudentParentInterface` not `student` obj directly.

parent call `getSchedule()` method on `StudentParentInterface`, is this correct?

Comment: Is there a reason the Parent could not make a call to Sudent.getSchedule() and such? What expansion do you see in the future that will make a StudentParentInterface useful?

Comment: @BlueHat I dont want to Parent has access to all method of student like addHomeWorkAnswer() or something like this.

Comment: That's fair enough, addHomeWorkAnswer() doesn't seem like something related to the student to me. Ignoring that though, you don't have to call all of the methods avalible to student from the Parent, they would be separate classes but to me they seem to have a direct one-to-many relationship rather than needing some sort of link. It looks to me like you may need to review what your classes do keeping SOLID in mind and I expect your answer will probably come out of that. I'd be reluctant to add this linking class  though since they seem to have a direct relationship themselves.

Comment: @BlueHat thnx for your attention, yes I check and addHomeWorkAnswer()  does not belong to student. before all of this is it true to put getSchedule() method in Student class?

Comment: I'll submit my response as an answer :)

Comment: Your associations don't have verbs to explain the relationships (for OO analysis). What is the class `StudentCourse` exactly? Is it the same as an offering of a course? I don't understand CourseClass at all.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Yes `StudentCourse` is for offering a course(cuz student and course have Many-To-Many relation I use this middle class). `CourseClass` is for representing time and location of a Course(Course can have more than one time&location in a week) .

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments on the OP, I don't think an interfacing class class makes sense in this instance since there is a direct relationship between Students and Parents.

Think about the relationships of the concepts outside of the system. Does every student have a schedule?

By my limited knowledge I'd say it sounds like it. It also sounds like you'll want parents to possibly have something student.getGrades(). So your you'll probably have multiple parents to one student. The student wouldn't need to be aware of the parent but the parent needs to be aware of the student so each Parent object will have a Student property and would probably call getSchedule() and getGrades() etc.

Answer (score 1):

At a general level, the method needs to go with the object that has responsibility for the function.

Based upon your domain, the `Student` has the responsibility to provide a `GetSchedule()` method, as the `Student` owns the courses that it is taking.

And while the `Parent` may have a requirement to be able to see the `Student`s schedule, the responsibility to execute that method still lies with the `Student` and not the `Parent`.

So in the simple case, `GetSchedule()` belongs to the `Student`.

---

In the more complex case, you may have a requirement that says the `Parent` should be able to see the `Student`'s schedule without involving the `Student`.  At that point, you'll need another means to access the system so that the `Parent` can call the equivalent of `GetSchedule(Student)` and pass their `Student` as a parameter to the new method.

So you might create a class called `Registrar`, and a `Parent` can invoke `Registrar.GetSchedule(Parent.MyStudent)` in order to allow the `Parent` to find out the `Student`'s schedule without involving the `Student`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me if you're following an OO methodology that uses analysis first. That way, you first have classes that represent only the problem domain. Then you consider the same software classes, but you're allowed to deviate from that.

`getSchedule()` could be a method in a so-called [Use-case Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_%28object-oriented_design%29#Controller) also know as [Front Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) which can be seen as a special case of the [Mediator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern).

#### TL;DR

If you're having trouble finding the right place to put a method because it doesn't really go with any of the existing classes responsibilities (it violates the cohesion principle), then it's OK to create a separate class that handles that function. Craig Larman calls this a [Pure Fabrication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_%28object-oriented_design%29#Pure_Fabrication), or a class that doesn't map to the problem domain. In your case, you could call it `ScheduleManager`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, do you mean use `ScheduleManager` for both Student and Parent or just Parent Class, Student has his own `getSchedule()` method and by this do I have code duplication? I mean two times write code to show schedule.

Comment: Don't duplicate code. `ScheduleManager` can have the responsibility to do that for students and parents.

Comment: Could you please tell the reason of this decision, I want to use this decision for other method and responsibilities. cuz at least `Student` class is expert for showing schedule ( it has link to `StudentCourse`...) is this true?

Comment: Pure Fabrication (see the link and the reference by Craig Larman) is the reason for the decision.